# Transições, Efeitos para WinForms .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, framework, visual-basic-6, transição

Como obter os efeitos de fade-in e out, transições, movimentações e etc, em formulários e seus controles no VB.NET, de forma nativa ou com uso de FrameWorks?

Comment: Postei somente como obter os efeitos de *fade in/out*, outros efeitos podem ser vistos no artigo [Image Transition in VB.NET Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43605/Image-Transition-in-VB-NET-Windows-Forms)

Answer (score 1):

Pode-ser manipular a propriedade [`Opacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do formulário para obter esse efeito. Segue um [exemplo](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/code/339714/simple-way-to-add-a-fade-effect):

```vb
Public Sub fadeIn()
    For fade = 0.0 To 1.1 Step 0.1
        Me.Opacity = fade
        Me.Refresh()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub fadeOut()
    For fade = 90 To 10 Step -10
        Me.Opacity = fade / 100
        Me.Refresh()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Next
End Sub
```

Nos eventos `Form1_Load` e `Form1_FormClosing` você faz:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
 Handles MyBase.Load
    fadeIn()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) 
 Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    fadeOut()
End Sub
```